# scala filter a list based on the values of another list

Tags: list, scala, filter

I have two lists:

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val l2 = List(true, false, true, true)
```

Is there a nice and short way to filter `l1` based on `l2`?

`ris = List(1, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little shorter:

```
list1.zip(list2).collect { case (x, true) => x }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be zipping and then filtering `l1.zip(l2).filter(_._2).map(_._1)` :

```
scala> l1.zip(l2)
res0: List[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (2,false), (3,true), (4,true))

scala> .filter(_._2)
res1: List[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (3,true), (4,true))

scala> .map(_._1)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for comprehension which desugars into `flatMap` and `withFilter` (lazy filtering), like this,

```
for ( (a,b) <- l1.zip(l2) if b ) yield a
```